# Does dereference equal to a function call?

Tags: rust

What happens if I borrow a dereferenced pointer?

```
let a = some object;
let b = &a;
let c = &*b;
```

What object has c borrowed? Does the dereferencing op create a temporary object like a function's return value? How does it obey the borrowing rules.

I'm also confused about Box's mutable semantic.

```
let mut a = Box::new(8us)
*a = 1;
```

This code works just fine without something like Box::new_mut(). But

```
let mut a = &8us;
*a = 1;
```

An error occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick answer: It depends.

Long answer: keep reading...

> What happens if I borrow a dereferenced pointer?
>   If you check out the LLVM-IR that rust generates, you can see everything in fine detail:

```
let a = 8us;
let b = &a;
let c = &*b;
```

gets expanded to

```
let a;
// %a = alloca i64
let b;
// %b = alloca i64*
let c;
// %c = alloca i64*
a = 8us;
// store i64 8, i64* %a
b = &a;
// store i64* %a, i64** %b
let tmp = *b;
// %0 = load i64** %b
c = tmp;
// store i64* %0, i64** %c
```

now, llvm can easily optimize this stuff out. It gets more complicated once you implement traits like [Deref](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Deref.html) on your own types. Then obviously a function call is involved, but most likely optimized out again, since you shouldn't be doing complicated stuff in the deref function.

> What object has c borrowed?

`c` borrows `a`

> Does the dereferencing op create a temporary object like a function's return value?

Nope, see above

> How does it obey the borrowing rules.

`*b` behaves as if it were `a`. If you take a reference to it you get a reference to `a`.

---

To answer your second issue:

A `Box` owns the object it points to. Since you declared your `Box` to be mutable, you can take eithe a mutable reference or any number of non-mutable references to your object. This means when you dereference the `Box` rust decides, depending the situation, whether to automatically create a mutable box. In the case of the assignment, your deref'd box is on the left side of the assignment operator, therefor rust tries to get a mutable reference to the object.

If you give your variables types, this becomes more obvious:

```
let mut x = Box::new(8us);
{
    let y : &usize = &*x;
}
{
    let y : &mut usize = &mut *x;
    *x = 99; // cannot assign to `*x` because it is borrowed
}
```

Comment: Your answer is wrong: `c` stores an alias to `a`.  `*b` is **not** a stack temporary, it's an rvalue alias to `a`.  This can be verified with a short program: http://is.gd/CLu5WQ

Comment: "c borrows a temporary stack allocated object" This really surprised me and I went to check it out. See [here](http://is.gd/fmergJ). It means that no, `c` borrows `a` and not the copy of `a`. Otherwise it would be quite confusing.

Comment: i forgot about rvalue references :/

Comment: In my second issue I was asking why Box can be mutated without something like Box::new_mut(8us);

Comment: @DK Does the rvalue aliase c borrow b?

Comment: @ker Yes. I get a deeper understanding of Box's deref op. I'm still confused about the rvalue aliase mutation.